# Python Pandas - sum a boolean variable by hour

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pretty simple question: I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like:

```
                     y
2015-12-09 09:00:00  1
2015-12-09 08:48:00  1
2015-12-09 08:24:00  1
2015-12-09 08:12:00  1
2015-12-09 08:00:00  1
2015-12-09 06:36:00  1
2015-12-09 06:24:00  1
...                 ..
2015-12-08 10:12:00  1
2015-12-08 10:00:00  1
2015-12-08 09:48:00  1
2015-12-08 09:36:00  1
```

I want to sum the boolean variables by hour, so I have something that looks like:

```
                     y
2015-12-09 09:00:00  1
2015-12-09 08:00:00  4
2015-12-09 07:00:00  0
2015-12-09 06:00:00  2
...                 ..
2015-12-08 10:00:00  2
2015-12-08 09:00:00  2
```

I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

It doesn't seem like a very hard problem, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is relatively straightforward, but it does implicitly assume that in your data set, `0` equates to `False` (which seems logical to me). If so, this works:

`df.resample('1H', how='sum').fillna(0)`

Else you may have to look into a different way of sorting through your data.

Comment: This is the exact snippet I was missing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Pandas newbie but here are my two cents.

Let's start with a `DataFrame` that looks like this (like yours):

[image]

What I did first was converting that string date-time into a date-time field:

```
data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['datetime'])
```

Then I created another column with only `date` values:

```
data['date'] = abc.datetime.dt.date
```

And another one with `hour` values:

```
data['hour'] = data.datetime.dt.hour
```

So my `data` DataFrame looks like this:

[image]

Finally, I just grouped by `date` and `hour`:

```
data.groupby(['date', 'hour']).size()
```

And these are the results:

[image]

If you don't want to alter your DataFrame just use a copy of it like:

```
mutable_data = data
```

And then make changes to `mutable_data`.

I hope this helps. If not, I would love to receive suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I thought about going about it this way but I thought that there may be a more elegant and pythonic way. That answer is Wouda.

Comment: @MakleBirt thank you for your words. I'm glad you got answered correctly. I have learned as well!